# Setting up site in sublime text ftp manager

Tags: ftp, sublimetext3

I have a perfectly working instance of WinSCP that I"m using for ftp. I have no problems with it but it's inconvenient and I want to use FTP within sublime text

I installed the SFTP/FTP package and trying to setup my remote server but the connection times out every time.

WinSCP details from site manager:

```
File Protocol: FTP 
Encryption: TLS/SSL Implicit Encryption
Host Name: ftp.testUser.testSite
port number: 990
user name: ftp.testUser.testSite|testUser
password: test123!
```

Current sftp-config.json file:

```
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "ftp",

    "sync_down_on_open": true,
    "sync_same_age": true,

    "host": "ftp.testUser.testSite",
    "user": "ftp.testUser.testSite|testUser",
    "password": "test123!",
    "port": "990",

    "remote_path": "C:/users/testUser/ftpweb/siteFolder",
    //"file_permissions": "664",
    //"dir_permissions": "775",

    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    //"keepalive": 120,
    "ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
    //"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
    "allow_config_upload": true,
}
```

Comment: The mention of implicit encryption and port 990 make me think that you might be using `ftps` and not regular `ftp` (even though it says that). I would try changing the type of the connection and see if that helps.